# Android bluetooth fluoride build how to link libraries

Tags: android-bluetooth

I'm trying to build fluoride using this repo https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/Bluetooth/+/refs/heads/master

I follow the README.md instructions to build on Linux but during the build a problem occurs with libbt_topshim/cxxbridge in btadapterd (rust part).

rust config on Debian 11

```
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/user/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
1.61.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)
```

cxxbridge version is 1.0.78

I installed dependencies and did the following commands

```
./build.py --run-bootstrap
./build.py
```

Output

```
"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.1qguycxee9jw17qa.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::a2dp::ffi::GetA2dpProfile':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/a2dp.rs:129: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$GetA2dpProfile'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.1qguycxee9jw17qa.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::a2dp::ffi::A2dpIntf::init':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/a2dp.rs:129: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$A2dpIntf$init'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.1qguycxee9jw17qa.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::a2dp::ffi::A2dpIntf::connect':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/a2dp.rs:129: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$A2dpIntf$connect'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.1qguycxee9jw17qa.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::a2dp::ffi::A2dpIntf::disconnect':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/a2dp.rs:129: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$A2dpIntf$disconnect'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.1qguycxee9jw17qa.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::a2dp::ffi::A2dpIntf::set_active_device':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/a2dp.rs:129: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$A2dpIntf$set_active_device'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.1qguycxee9jw17qa.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::a2dp::ffi::A2dpIntf::set_audio_config':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/a2dp.rs:129: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$A2dpIntf$set_audio_config'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.1qguycxee9jw17qa.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::a2dp::ffi::A2dpIntf::start_audio_request':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/a2dp.rs:129: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$A2dpIntf$start_audio_request'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.1qguycxee9jw17qa.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::a2dp::ffi::A2dpIntf::stop_audio_request':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/a2dp.rs:129: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$A2dpIntf$stop_audio_request'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.1qguycxee9jw17qa.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::a2dp::ffi::A2dpIntf::get_presentation_position':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/a2dp.rs:129: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$A2dpIntf$get_presentation_position'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.1qguycxee9jw17qa.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::a2dp::ffi::A2dpIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__raw':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/a2dp.rs:164: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$A2dpIntf$raw'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.1qguycxee9jw17qa.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::a2dp::ffi::A2dpIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__get':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/a2dp.rs:164: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$A2dpIntf$get'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.1qguycxee9jw17qa.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::a2dp::ffi::A2dpIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__drop':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/a2dp.rs:164: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$A2dpIntf$drop'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::GetGattClientProfile':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$GetGattClientProfile'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::GattClientIntf::read_phy':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$GattClientIntf$read_phy'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::GetBleScannerIntf':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$GetBleScannerIntf'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleScannerIntf::RegisterScanner':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleScannerIntf$RegisterScanner'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleScannerIntf::Unregister':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleScannerIntf$Unregister'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleScannerIntf::Scan':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleScannerIntf$Scan'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleScannerIntf::RegisterCallbacks':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleScannerIntf$RegisterCallbacks'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::GetBleAdvertiserIntf':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$GetBleAdvertiserIntf'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleAdvertiserIntf::Unregister':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleAdvertiserIntf$Unregister'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleAdvertiserIntf::GetOwnAddress':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleAdvertiserIntf$GetOwnAddress'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleAdvertiserIntf::SetParameters':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleAdvertiserIntf$SetParameters'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleAdvertiserIntf::SetData':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleAdvertiserIntf$SetData'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleAdvertiserIntf::Enable':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleAdvertiserIntf$Enable'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleAdvertiserIntf::StartAdvertisingSet':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleAdvertiserIntf$StartAdvertisingSet'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleAdvertiserIntf::SetPeriodicAdvertisingParameters':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleAdvertiserIntf$SetPeriodicAdvertisingParameters'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleAdvertiserIntf::SetPeriodicAdvertisingData':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleAdvertiserIntf$SetPeriodicAdvertisingData'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleAdvertiserIntf::RegisterCallbacks':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:26: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$BleAdvertiserIntf$RegisterCallbacks'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::GattClientIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__raw':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:113: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$GattClientIntf$raw'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::GattClientIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__get':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:113: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$GattClientIntf$get'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::GattClientIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__drop':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:113: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$GattClientIntf$drop'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleScannerIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__raw':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:135: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$BleScannerIntf$raw'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleScannerIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__get':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:135: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$BleScannerIntf$get'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleScannerIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__drop':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:135: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$BleScannerIntf$drop'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleAdvertiserIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__raw':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:287: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$BleAdvertiserIntf$raw'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleAdvertiserIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__get':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:287: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$BleAdvertiserIntf$get'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.3wcouwzkxm54yos5.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::gatt::ffi::BleAdvertiserIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__drop':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/gatt.rs:287: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$BleAdvertiserIntf$drop'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.4npg2mfzrw5zt62b.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::avrcp::ffi::GetAvrcpProfile':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/avrcp.rs:7: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$GetAvrcpProfile'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.4npg2mfzrw5zt62b.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::avrcp::ffi::AvrcpIntf::init':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/avrcp.rs:7: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$AvrcpIntf$init'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.4npg2mfzrw5zt62b.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::avrcp::ffi::AvrcpIntf::connect':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/avrcp.rs:7: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$AvrcpIntf$connect'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.4npg2mfzrw5zt62b.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::avrcp::ffi::AvrcpIntf::disconnect':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/avrcp.rs:7: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$AvrcpIntf$disconnect'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.4npg2mfzrw5zt62b.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::avrcp::ffi::AvrcpIntf::set_volume':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/avrcp.rs:7: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$AvrcpIntf$set_volume'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.4npg2mfzrw5zt62b.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::avrcp::ffi::AvrcpIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__raw':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/avrcp.rs:19: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$AvrcpIntf$raw'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.4npg2mfzrw5zt62b.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::avrcp::ffi::AvrcpIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__get':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/avrcp.rs:19: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$AvrcpIntf$get'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.4npg2mfzrw5zt62b.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::profiles::avrcp::ffi::AvrcpIntf as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__drop':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/avrcp.rs:19: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$AvrcpIntf$drop'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.55gfuaihjw4ik3pl.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::btif::ffi::ConvertFlags':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/btif.rs:677: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$ConvertFlags'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.55gfuaihjw4ik3pl.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::btif::ffi::InitFlags::GetFlagsPtr':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/btif.rs:677: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$InitFlags$GetFlagsPtr'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.55gfuaihjw4ik3pl.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::btif::ffi::InitFlags as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__raw':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/btif.rs:691: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$InitFlags$raw'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.55gfuaihjw4ik3pl.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::btif::ffi::InitFlags as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__get':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/btif.rs:691: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$InitFlags$get'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.55gfuaihjw4ik3pl.rcgu.o): in function `<bt_topshim::btif::ffi::InitFlags as cxx::unique_ptr::UniquePtrTarget>::__drop':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/btif.rs:691: undefined reference to `cxxbridge1$unique_ptr$bluetooth$topshim$rust$InitFlags$drop'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.clgyq82hw2j7amz.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::metrics::ffi::adapter_state_changed':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/metrics.rs:3: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$adapter_state_changed'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.clgyq82hw2j7amz.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::metrics::ffi::bond_create_attempt':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/metrics.rs:3: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$bond_create_attempt'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.clgyq82hw2j7amz.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::metrics::ffi::bond_state_changed':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/metrics.rs:3: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$bond_state_changed'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.clgyq82hw2j7amz.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::metrics::ffi::device_info_report':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/metrics.rs:3: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$device_info_report'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.clgyq82hw2j7amz.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::metrics::ffi::profile_connection_state_changed':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/metrics.rs:3: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$profile_connection_state_changed'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.l4l4hytww9nnhbu.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::btif::get_btinterface':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/btif.rs:1198: undefined reference to `hal_util_load_bt_library(bt_interface_t const**)'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.vpfpdvw5mhps2xh.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::hfp::ffi::GetHfpProfile':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/hfp.rs:63: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$GetHfpProfile'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.vpfpdvw5mhps2xh.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::hfp::ffi::HfpIntf::init':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/hfp.rs:63: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$HfpIntf$init'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.vpfpdvw5mhps2xh.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::hfp::ffi::HfpIntf::connect':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/hfp.rs:63: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$HfpIntf$connect'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.vpfpdvw5mhps2xh.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::hfp::ffi::HfpIntf::connect_audio':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/hfp.rs:63: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$HfpIntf$connect_audio'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.floss/output/debug/deps/libbt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.rlib(bt_topshim-b219733fc9b61ad8.vpfpdvw5mhps2xh.rcgu.o): in function `bt_topshim::profiles::hfp::ffi::HfpIntf::set_active_device':
          /home/user/tools/fluoride/Bluetooth/system/gd/rust/topshim/src/profiles/hfp.rs:63: undefined reference to `bluetooth$topshim$rust$cxxbridge1$HfpIntf$set_active_device'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          
  = help: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)

error: could not compile `btadapterd` due to previous error
```

The C++ build part is working well

```
Number of jobs = 4
Building target  main
ninja: Entering directory `/home/user/.floss/output/out/Default'
ninja: no work to do.
```

Libraries are located in /home/user/.floss/output/out/Default

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     4230 30 sept. 11:02 libaudio_hal_interface.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    19092 30 sept. 11:02 libbluetooth.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    81734 30 sept. 11:02 libbluetooth_gd.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user        8 30 sept. 10:53 libbluetooth_rust_interop.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 16620010 30 sept. 11:02 libbluetooth-static.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user        8 30 sept. 11:02 libbluetooth_topshim.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1124316 30 sept. 11:02 libbta.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    20086 30 sept. 10:53 libbtcore.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1723744 30 sept. 11:02 libbtif.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    10444 30 sept. 10:53 libbt_keystore_cc.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     4308 30 sept. 11:02 libbt-platform-protos-lite.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   187554 30 sept. 11:02 libcommon.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     4082 30 sept. 10:53 libcrypto_toolbox.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user      824 30 sept. 10:53 libdevice.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user      472 30 sept. 10:51 libg722.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    18206 30 sept. 11:02 libhci.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    87850 30 sept. 11:02 libosi.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   252950 30 sept. 10:53 libpacket.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   407454 30 sept. 11:02 libprofile_avrcp.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user        8 30 sept. 10:51 libsbc.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     7236 30 sept. 11:02 libtypes.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user      430 30 sept. 11:02 libutils.a
```

Comment: Could you solve the issue? Same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a transient build error.  Should work.

You can also try the build dpkg if you want to install and run it on ubuntu.